# find out cell address having = sheet name

Tags: vba, excel

I'm just a beginner for VBA but advance in MS excel. that's why I am very much interested to learn VBA.
ok this is my first question here

Actully i need to format excel sheet where file name is = sheet1 name and it is somewhere in column "A" so I want to select & delete all the rows above this cell & below untill there is a blank cell/row.

I have tried much with InStr & find function but no succeed. Also try to find cell address like B5 but could no do that.

Comment: Post what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. As you have already been informed by newguy, when posting a question you should also show what you have tried so far... some piece of code, printscreens, etc.

Your explanation was not that clear (at least to me), but based on what I have understood, I have made a small code sample for you to get you started. I have broken down the code into the function blocks, so that you can better understand what they are trying to achieve.

Here is the code:

```
'the following function will find cell with the specific text
Private Function FindCell(ws As Worksheet, strToSearch As String, Optional sColumn As String = "A") As Integer
    Dim iCounter As Integer

    'as you do not know where exactly it exists, we loop from first cell in the particular row
    'to the very last celll
    With ws
        For iCounter = 1 To .Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row ' or .UsedRange.Rows.Count, or any other method
            If .Range(sColumn & iCounter).Value = strToSearch Then
                'yay, we have found the cell!
                'pass out the reference
                FindCell = iCounter

                'now call exit function as we no longer need to continue searching for the cell (we have already found it!)
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next iCounter
    End With

    'in case the cell does not exist, we can return -1
    FindCell = -1
End Function

'the following cell will search the very first cell to the top (starting from specific row), which is blank / empty
Private Function FindEmptyCell(ws As Worksheet, iStartRow As Integer, Optional sColumn As String = "A") As Integer
        'This function does the same, as if you have selected specific cell
        'and then pressed left Ctrl + Up arrow at the same time
        'Try it!
        'You can do the same with Right + Left + Bottom arrow as well
        FindEmptyCell = ws.Range(sColumn & iStartRow).End(xlUp).Row + 1
End Function

Private Sub EraseRows()
    Dim iStartCell As Integer
    Dim iEndCell As Integer
    On Error GoTo 0
    'First let's find the "bottom" cell which is the cell with the specific text you are looking for
    iEndCell = FindCell(ActiveSheet, "TextIAmLookingFor")

    'now let's see find the top blank cell (so that we get the range of from - to that you want to erase)
    iStartCell = FindEmptyCell(ActiveSheet, iEndCell)

    'now we can delete the rows!
    'iEndCell-1 because you don't want to erase the cell with your search string, right?
    ActiveSheet.Rows(CStr(iStartCell) & ":" & CStr(iEndCell - 1)).EntireRow.Delete (xlUp)
End Sub
```